# How to detect if a pushed viewcontroller appears again?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

- assuming I have a viewcontroller **(vcA)** that pushes QRCodeScannerViewcontroller **(vcB)**. When **(vcB)** scanned something, It will push  ResultviewController **(vcC)**.

-Those 3 views is connected to a UInavigation controller

-the user clicks on the back button on **(vcC)**

my question is:

1)how can I know if **(vcB)** is visible without changing code on **(vcB)**? **(vcB)** is a pod

2)where will I put this code? I can only access **(vcA)**

i tried adding this code on **(vcA)** but nothing happened

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if (vcB.isViewLoaded && (vcB.view.window != nil)){
        print("vcb did appear!")
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't write code inside cvB nor vcC?

Comment: i can but i prefer not to alter cvB as it is pod. although I can alter vcC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know if an instance of cvB's class exists in the navigation stack, you could use this piece of code:

```
let result = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.filter({
    if let vcB = $0 as? UIViewController { // Replace UIViewController with your class, for example ViewControllerB
        return true
    }
    return false
})

if result.isEmpty {
    print("An instance of vcB's class hasn't been pused before")
} else {
    print("An instance of vcB's class has been pused before")
}
```

Comment: My goal here is know if cvB did appear. Where will i put this code?

Comment: Put it wherever you want to do that check. Where do you want to check for that?

Comment: can i put this on vcA? on viewWilappear?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But try to choose a logical place for this check, this depends on your application's logic.

Comment: thanks, will accept this as answer after I test some few things.